# How to delay output in C++?

Tags: c++, output, delay

I am doing a project that need to read data from a file.
But before the file is opened i want to display  `Loading . . . . .` 
I want the dots after "Loading" to get printed one by one and each after about 2-3 seconds and then i display my file's contents. That is, after first 3 seconds `Loading .` displays and after another 3 seconds `Loading . .` displays and so on.
I Couldn't find a way to do, please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is platform-dependent.

On Windows, you may use [Sleep()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

```
Sleep(3000);
```

The parameter is the amount of time in milliseconds. You need to include windows.h in order to use this function.

On POSIX-compatible, you may use sleep():

```
sleep(3); // parameter is in seconds
```

If you need better precision, you may use usleep():

```
usleep(3000000); // parameter is in microseconds
```

For both functions, you need to include unistd.h

Comment: Is this really a C++ answer? Which C++ header contains those functions?

Answer (score 1):

In c++11, you can create a thread that loop on sleep 3sec and print dots just before reading the file. You must use condition or variable guarded by mutex to exit the thread.

Answer (score 0):

2 basic solutions:

1 use sleep() of usleep() to block it.
2. use a while loop to let cpu busy loop.

In production, we usualy do the first solution. But be cautious about this always. make sure this is what you want to do.

Another way is,
use a event loop approach and set a timer for this event. it can be ran later after timer is timed-out

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you can use:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
...
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
...
std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
```